# Why is bundler doing this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundle, bundler

I have an EngineYard deployment that is failing due to certain gems not being found in vendor/cache. But look at what happens when I run "bundle":

```
Updating .gem files in vendor/cache 
  * rspec-core-2.6.0.rc6.gem
  * rspec-expectations-2.6.0.rc6.gem
  * rspec-mocks-2.6.0.rc6.gem
  * rspec-2.6.0.rc6.gem
  * rspec-rails-2.6.0.rc6.gem
Removing outdated .gem files from vendor/cache
  * rspec-2.6.0.rc6.gem
  * rspec-core-2.6.0.rc6.gem
  * rspec-expectations-2.6.0.rc6.gem
  * rspec-mocks-2.6.0.rc6.gem
  * rspec-rails-2.6.0.rc6.gem
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

These are the gems that are causing a problem with my deployment. First it says it's updating them, then it says it's deleting them. How do I fix this?

Comment: Which bundler version are you running? (`bundle -v`)

Comment: version 1.0.10. Now I have 1.0.13, same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the answer to my question, but I was able to fix it by removing a requirement for a specific release-candidate version gem from my Gemfile, then:

```
gem cleanup
bundle update
bundle
```

That fixed it.